# Call api with Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to consume athe api located at `http://base-url/delivery-orders?driverId.equals=1116`

This is my function:

```
@GET("delivery-orders")
fun getAllDeliveryOrder(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Query("driverId") idDriver: Int
): Observable<OrderItems>
```

but I got error code 500.

Answer (score 2):

Error codes from 500-599 are server errors. Meaning, your code is working but the server doesn't. Better recheck the code from the server to fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

This problem usually from server..
try to check Method or maybe there has invinity looping.

My friend also get the same problem, he say you must check database. Maybe your web can't call some data in database. just try delete all or make empty database, and then run again ur Android

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem about that request. the problem is the URL have `driverId.equal` and my network interface is

`@GET("delivery-orders")
    fun getAllDeliveryOrder(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Query("driverId") idDriver: Int): Observable<OrderItems>`

so retrofit think `driverId` on URL is `driverId` in `@Query`, so I just change `"driverId"` in `@Query` with `IdDriver`. that solve the problem.